# Cross layer in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

How can I add a cross layer in pytorch (https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05123). I would like to add such a cross layer into my neural network that comes before the deep layers as a way to better combine my features that are coming from a range of sources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a PyTorch implementation of the DCN architecture from paper you linked in the [DeepCTR-Torch library](https://deepctr-torch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick-Start.html). You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/shenweichen/DeepCTR-Torch/blob/master/deepctr_torch/models/dcn.py

If you `pip install deepctr-torch` then you can just use the `CrossNet` layer as a `torch.Module`:

```py
from deepctr_torch.layers.interaction import CrossNet

crossnet = CrossNet(in_features=512)
```